# Refresh a component from different component

Tags: angular

Hello I'm using Angular 7, here's the component's structure:

[image]

I'm sending data from Comp_3 to Comp_2 in order to update 'Message'. But those data are sent at Comp_2's initizialisation only.

I want to update 'Messsage' when I modify 'List A', 'List B' or 'List C'.

I'm sending data from Comp_3 to Comp_2 when Comp_2 is loading Comp_3. But I don't know how reload Comp_2 when List B or C is updated. And same thing about when List A from Comp_1 is updated. I thought about calling Comp_2.ngInit() but I don't know how to make it.

Comp_0:

```
<Comp_0>
    <ng-template #content>
        <Comp_1 *ngIf="productConf" [dossier]="productConf" [productId]="productId" [metadata]="metadataProductConfIdentBlock"></Comp_1>
        <Comp_2 *ngIf="productConf && product" [revisionId]="revisionId" [List_A]="List_A" [dossier]="productConf" [productId]="productId"
            [product]="product" [metadata]="metadataProductConfContentBlock">
        </Comp_2>
    </ng-template>
</Comp_0>
```

List A from Comp_1:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-2 data-line ui-g-offset-1" >
    <div class="label-field">Standard</div>
    <cmpm-autoComplete appendTo="body" [disabled]="readOnly || !isUpdatable('product.confIdentStandard')"
      [checkListModalForm]="getProductCheckListModalForm('product.confIdentStandard', productId)"
      [metadata]="metadata" [forceSelection]="true" type="text" [dropdown]="true" [autoHighlight]="true"
      [suggestions]="standardSuggestions" field="code" (onSelect)="clearMsn()" (onClear)="clearStandard()"
      (completeMethod)="loadStandardSuggestions($event)" formControlName="standard" [multiple]="false">
    </cmpm-autoComplete>
</div>
```

List B or C from Comp_3:

```
<p-column field="targetedStandards" sortField="targetedStandards" [sortable]="true" header="Targeted Standard(s)" [style]="{'width':'170px'}">
  <ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <cmpm-autoComplete appendTo="body" field="code" [forceSelection]="true" [dropdown]="true"
      [autoHighlight]="true" [suggestions]="standardSuggestion" (completeMethod)="searchStandard($event)"
      [multiple]="true" [checkable]="true" [disabled]="!isEdit" (onSelect)="saveRow(row)"
      (onUnselect)="saveRow(row)" (onSelectAll)="selectAllStandard($event, row)" addAllLabel="ALL ST"
      [addAll]="true" disabledText="" [(ngModel)]="row[col.field]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </cmpm-autoComplete>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Comp_3 ts (where I send data from Comp_3 to Comp_2 at the Comp_2's initialization):

```
 @Output() linkedObjectForModal: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() objectLinkForModal: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() reloadComponent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
    this.linkedObjects = this.project.linkedObjects;
    this.iccCrService.searchIccCrForProject(this.acProgram, this.productConfId, "").subscribe((values) => {
      this.objectLinkForModal.emit(values);
    });
    this.linkedObjectForModal.emit(this.project);
    this.reloadComponent.emit("TEST");
  }

refreshAnomalies(value) {
    this.reloadComponent.next('Call function from Parent ?');
  }
```

I'm really stuck on this problem any help would be nice, many thanks !

ps: If you need more code, let me know.

Comment: simple add stackblitz demo of this problem, it would be more useful

Comment: Sorry for the question. What's the use of reloading the component 3 when you updated the list this component contains?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I'm sure it will but this a complex code and I can't just create a simple demo of this issue.

Comment: @Lynx242 It's my mistake, it's not Comp_3 I want to reload, it's Comp_2, I edit the question.

Comment: This would be very complex with input and output decorators. This complexity can be easily mitigated with angular services and obsrevables.

Comment: simply, explain flow of your structure..

Comment: @A.T. I read some doc' about `@Input` and `@Output`. But is that what I have to use to reload Comp_2 when I modify 'List B or C' ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Does the image is not enough to explain the structure ?

Comment: You have one container component. Then inside container component you have two child component. when child component update property you want to update property of container component . Is it correct ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I want to update Comp_2 when List_A from Comp_1 is updated or when List_B / List_C from Comp_3 is updated.

Comment: To update comp_2 means, you want complete reload or just else ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Complete reload of Comp_2, like runing ngInit() I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231310/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-majestic).

Answer (score 2):

Use rxjs operator Subject -
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject

Initialize your message object as a subject, subscribe on it in your component 2.
When you update your List in component 1 or component 3, just call `.next()` function upon your subject.

// EDIT:

check comment for this answer from [Arnaud Denoyelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192903/arnaud-denoyelle) as he explains how to create the subject

Comment: I think that an important part is missing : the `Subject` shall be created as a variable of a `Service`. All components will inject the same instance of the service and then share the same instance of the subject. It might be obvious for you but not for the OP

Comment: you are right, edited the answer with reference on your comment, thank you :}